# Value of output "any" when there are no rows in the SQL table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
$successreturn[]=array(
                    "id"=>"any",
                    "firstname"=>"any",
                    "lastname"=>"any",
                    "dateofbirth"=>"any",
                    "city"=>"any",
                    "gender"=>"any"
                );
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="sandeepchetikam";
$dbase="mydb";

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbase);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection Problem".mysqli_connect_error($conn);
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM Employees";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$value=0;

if(!$result){
    echo "Connection Failed " .mysqli_connect_error($result);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $successreturn[$value]['id']            =$row['id'];
    $successreturn[$value]['firstname']     =$row['firstname'];
    $successreturn[$value]['lastname']      =$row['lastname'];
    $successreturn[$value]['dateofbirth']   =$row['dateofbirth'];
    $successreturn[$value]['city']          =$row['city'];
    $successreturn[$value]['gender']        =$row['gender'];
    $value++;
};
echo json_encode($successreturn);
?>
```

output :

```
[{"id":"any","firstname":"any","lastname":"any","dateofbirth":"any","city":"any","gender":"any"}]
```

I am trying to return a JSON value into my angular service. But when there are no more rows in the table. Its returning the Colomn value as "any". 
Why is it like that ?? How do i return a empty row with no value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to control the program flow a little differently

```
<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="sandeepchetikam";
$dbase="mydb";

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbase);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection Problem".mysqli_connect_error($conn);
}

// first only select what you want to use from the row
$sql= "SELECT `id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,
              `dateofbirth`,`city`,`gender`
         FROM Employees";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(!$result){
    // you only use `mysqli_connect_error` to get connection errors
    // use mysqli_error($result) for normal query errors
    echo "Query failed " . mysqli_error($result);
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Query failed'));
    exit;
}

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // now as you only have what you want in your assoc array
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    // no data returned from query
    // return something so the calling code knows what to do
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>'No data in table'));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When no row selected then the while loop is not executting and the initial $successreturn array is return with value *'any'* to return no value if no row selected then

Just change this

```
$successreturn[]=array(
        "id"=>"any",
       "firstname"=>"any",
      "lastname"=>"any",
    "dateofbirth"=>"any",
    "city"=>"any",
    "gender"=>"any");
```

To

```
$successreturn[]=array(
        "id"=>"",
       "firstname"=>"",
      "lastname"=>"",
    "dateofbirth"=>"",
    "city"=>"",
    "gender"=>"");
```

**Edit:-**

```
$successreturn=[];
```

And check the value is empty or not in view and then display the data if it have otherwise don't display it.
I thing it will help you.

Comment: This will of course now return an array containing empty values instead of an array containing `any`. Which may not be what the OP wants

Comment: What if I don't want to return any value when there is no data available??

Comment: then you can return empty array or false.

Comment: @Prakash what do u wanna do when there;'s no data?

Comment: I am returning it to a table in my page. So its showing a row with no data but with edit and delete buttons. I just dont want any output when there is no data.

Comment: Okay then just do like this $successreturn=[]; and in the view check the response is empty or not if empty nothing to do with it or if it has value then display it.